# c# DateTime convert to string

Tags: c#, datetime, tostring

I have a result set with some times stored in DateTime variables.  If the value is null I want to set the var to the string "Still logged in".

I've tried some toString() things but had no luck yet.

This is the code that doesn't work.  queryResult.Egresstime is type DateTime and can't be a string.

```
if (Convert.IsDBNull(rdr["timeOut"]))
                {
                    queryResult.Egresstime = "Still logged in";
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems like a flaw in design but if you absolutely must keep it like this, you could set it to a precise date ridiculously far in the past and check before rendering the date to render "Still logged in" if it's that particular date.  That is a terrible way to design things though!

Comment: That is exactly what I did, easy to spot to 1/1/1111

Comment: I agree, bad design but I have done this in the past.  We usually go with the databases earliest possible date and give that special meaning.

Answer (score 0):

You are out of luck here - you can't assign a string to a property of type `DateTime`. It simply doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a string to a DateTime.

Perhaps you need to have another field indicating whether the time is valid, and if not, display the "Still logged in" text instead ?

If you are able to change EgressTime to be a nullable DateTime (`DateTime?`), you could use null to indicate that the value doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You cant store a string into Datetime !
But you can do this

```
Datetime? Egresstime ;

DateTime timeOut;
if(!DateTime.TryParse(rdr["timeOut"], out timeOut))
{
    Egresstime  = null;
}
If(Egresstime ==null)
{
//print still logged in
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to make it an `object` instead of a `DateTime`.

What I would do is make Egresstime a nullable DateTime (`DateTime?`) and set it to `null`.

```
if (Convert.IsDBNull(rdr["timeOut"]))
{
    queryResult.Egresstime = null;
}
```

Then right before I output it to my report/UI/whatever, I then check for null.

```
Egresstime.Text = queryResult.Egresstime == null ? "Still logged in" : Egresstime.ToString();
```